# Cocountable topology and limits of sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, convergence-divergence

I need help solving the following statements:

> Look at the interval $[0,1]$ with the topology
>   $$\mathcal T_c := \{M \subseteq [0,1]:M=\emptyset\quad or\quad [0,1] \backslash M \, is\, countable \}$$
>   respectively the cocountable topology on the interval [0,1].
>
> a) Show that, for all mutually distinct points $x,y\in [0,1]$, there exist no open sets $U$ and $V$ with $x\in U, y\in V$ such that $U\cap V = \emptyset$, but every convergent sequence has a unique limit.
>   b) Find a topology $\mathcal T_f \neq \mathcal T_c$ on $[0,1]$ such that a sequence converges with respect to $\mathcal T_c$ if, and only if, it converges with respect to $\mathcal T_f$.

Comment: For b), guessing from the subscript I think you can have a go at the cofinite topology.

Comment: @Vim: That idea turns out to fail very badly.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott ok I confess that I haven't even thought about the problem. It's just the $f$ subscript looks strongly like a hint to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HINT: For (a) let $x$ and $y$ be distinct points in $[0,1]$, let $U$ be an open nbhd of $x$, and let $V$ be an open nbhd of $y$.

- What do you know about the sets $[0,1]\setminus U$ and $[0,1]\setminus V$?
- How big is the union of two countable sets?
- Is $\Bbb R$ countable?

For (b), start by showing that a sequence $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ in $[0,1]$ converges to $x\in[0,1]$ if and only if there is an $m\in\Bbb N$ such that $x_n=x$ for all $n\ge m$. Then try to find a different topology on $[0,1]$ with the same property. (There is a very simple one that works.)

Comment: +1 for the fair observation in b). I didn't even fancy *the* topology as it looks so drastically different than the cocountable one.

Comment: Thanks so far, I wil try my best using your hints!

Comment: @bavor42: If you get completely stuck, feel free to leave a question.